# R, count frequency of ""

Tags: r, frequency

After I parse one html file, I got something like this and I'd like to count the frequency of "" (3rd line)

```
html_1

[1]"I'm working"
[2]" "
[3]""
[4]" "

class(html_1)
character
```

I would use table function for a normal dataframe, but as soon as I change this to a data frame, it becomes like the below, so I cannot distinguish "" and " " anymore.

```
html_2 <- as.data.frame(html_1)
html_2

I'm working
```

Any advice to count "" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one:

```
sum(html_1 == "")

sum(nchar(html_1) == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very concise answer =)

Answer (score 2):

This mostly builds on @Roman's answer but (1) shows you a different way to "see" the spaces and (2) shows you a different idea for tabulation:

```
html_1 <- c("I'm working here", " ", "", " ", "No", NA, "")
html_2 <- as.data.frame(html_1)
```

`print` has a `quote` argument that lets you put quotes around the columns so that you can see leading and trailing whitespace more easily. That's helpful here too.

```
print(html_2, quote = TRUE)
#               html_1
# 1 "I'm working here"
# 2                " "
# 3                 ""
# 4                " "
# 5               "No"
# 6                 NA
# 7                 ""
```

Tabulation is as simple as looking for a string that looks like `""`:

```
html_2$html_1 == ""
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE
table(html_2$html_1 == "")
# 
# FALSE  TRUE 
#     4     2
```

Alternatively, you can count how many characters there are in each item to get the same information. Here, `0` is obviously the string of interest (but I don't like that `NA` gets counted as two characters).

```
table(nchar(as.character(html_2$html_1)))
# 
#  0  1  2 16 
#  2  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to find empty strings:

```
html1 <- c("I'm working here", " ", "", " ")
idx <- grepl("^$", html1)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

In the code above, `^$` denotes `""`. Count the empty strings:

```
table(idx)
# idx
# FALSE  TRUE 
#     3     1
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I can use regular expressions for ""